# "make" command works on ubuntu VM but not on debian stretch

Tags: debian, autotools, autoconf

I recently upgraded to debian stretch. everything was fine until i tried to install a software from git. I installed build-essential, autoconf-dev and so on, but the "make" step keeps returning errors, whereas it didn't with my ubuntu 17.04.
here's the result of the ./configure :

```
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... yes
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking for GetProcessMemoryInfo in -lpsapi... no
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking getopt.h usability... yes
checking getopt.h presence... yes
checking for getopt.h... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking float.h usability... yes
checking float.h presence... yes
checking for float.h... yes
checking regex.h usability... yes
checking regex.h presence... yes
checking for regex.h... yes
checking ctype.h usability... yes
checking ctype.h presence... yes
checking for ctype.h... yes
checking locale.h usability... yes
checking locale.h presence... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking for size_t... yes
checking for uint32_t... yes
checking for int64_t... yes
checking for uint64_t... yes
checking for uint8_t... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes
checking for working strtod... yes
checking for working alloca.h... yes
checking for alloca... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible realloc... yes
checking for memmove... yes
checking for memcpy... yes
checking for posix_memalign... yes
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for localtime_r... yes
checking for memchr... yes
checking for memset... yes
checking for pow... yes
checking for regcomp... yes
checking for strcasecmp... yes
checking for strchr... yes
checking for strcspn... yes
checking for sysinfo... yes
checking for library containing pthread_create... none required
checking for ps2pdf... yes
checking pthread.h usability... yes
checking pthread.h presence... yes
checking for pthread.h... yes
checking bzlib.h usability... yes
checking bzlib.h presence... yes
checking for bzlib.h... yes
checking zlib.h usability... yes
checking zlib.h presence... yes
checking for zlib.h... yes
checking windows.h usability... no
checking windows.h presence... no
checking for windows.h... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating man/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
```

and here's the "make" result :

```
make  all-recursive
make[1] : on entre dans le répertoire « /home/dylan/vsearch »
Making all in src
make[2] : on entre dans le répertoire « /home/dylan/vsearch/src »
depbase=`echo align_simd.o | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.o$||'`;\
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..    -Wall -Wsign-compare -O3 -g -g -MT align_simd.o -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o align_simd.o align_simd.cc &&\
mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Po
align_simd.cc:99:9: error: ‘__m128i’ does not name a type
 typedef __m128i VECTOR_SHORT;
         ^~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:104:3: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ does not name a type
   VECTOR_SHORT matrix[32];
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:105:3: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ does not name a type
   VECTOR_SHORT * hearray;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:106:3: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ does not name a type
   VECTOR_SHORT * dprofile;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:107:3: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ does not name a type
   VECTOR_SHORT ** qtable;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:134:16: error: variable or field ‘_mm_print’ declared void
 void _mm_print(VECTOR_SHORT x)
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:134:16: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
align_simd.cc:141:17: error: variable or field ‘_mm_print2’ declared void
 void _mm_print2(VECTOR_SHORT x)
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:141:17: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
align_simd.cc: In function ‘void dprofile_fill16(CELL*, CELL*, BYTE*)’:
align_simd.cc:197:3: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
   VECTOR_SHORT reg0,  reg1,  reg2,  reg3,  reg4,  reg5,  reg6,  reg7;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:198:16: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘reg8’
   VECTOR_SHORT reg8,  reg9,  reg10, reg11, reg12, reg13, reg14, reg15;
                ^~~~
align_simd.cc:199:16: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘reg16’
   VECTOR_SHORT reg16, reg17, reg18, reg19, reg20, reg21, reg22, reg23;
                ^~~~~
align_simd.cc:200:16: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘reg24’
   VECTOR_SHORT reg24, reg25, reg26, reg27, reg28, reg29, reg30, reg31;
                ^~~~~
align_simd.cc:289:7: error: ‘reg0’ was not declared in this scope
       reg0  = _mm_load_si128((VECTOR_SHORT*)(score_matrix_word + d[0] + i));
       ^~~~
align_simd.cc:289:44: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
       reg0  = _mm_load_si128((VECTOR_SHORT*)(score_matrix_word + d[0] + i));
                                            ^
align_simd.cc:289:75: error: ‘_mm_load_si128’ was not declared in this scope
       reg0  = _mm_load_si128((VECTOR_SHORT*)(score_matrix_word + d[0] + i));
                                                                           ^
align_simd.cc:290:7: error: ‘reg1’ was not declared in this scope
       reg1  = _mm_load_si128((VECTOR_SHORT*)(score_matrix_word + d[1] + i));
       ^~~~
align_simd.cc:290:44: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
       reg1  = _mm_load_si128((VECTOR_SHORT*)(score_matrix_word + d[1] + i));
                                            ^
align_simd.cc:291:7: error: ‘reg2’ was not declared in this scope
       reg2  = _mm_load_si128((VECTOR_SHORT*)(score_matrix_word + d[2] + i));
       ^~~~
align_simd.cc:291:44: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
       reg2  = _mm_load_si128((VECTOR_SHORT*)(score_matrix_word + d[2] + i));
                                            ^
align_simd.cc:292:7: error: ‘reg3’ was not declared in this scope
       reg3  = _mm_load_si128((VECTOR_SHORT*)(score_matrix_word + d[3] + i));
       ^~~~
align_simd.cc:292:44: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
       reg3  = _mm_load_si128((VECTOR_SHORT*)(score_matrix_word + d[3] + i));
                                            ^
align_simd.cc:293:7: error: ‘reg4’ was not declared in this scope
       reg4  = _mm_load_si128((VECTOR_SHORT*)(score_matrix_word + d[4] + i));
       ^~~~
align_simd.cc:293:44: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
       reg4  = _mm_load_si128((VECTOR_SHORT*)(score_matrix_word + d[4] + i));
                                            ^
align_simd.cc:294:7: error: ‘reg5’ was not declared in this scope
       reg5  = _mm_load_si128((VECTOR_SHORT*)(score_matrix_word + d[5] + i));
       ^~~~
align_simd.cc:294:44: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
       reg5  = _mm_load_si128((VECTOR_SHORT*)(score_matrix_word + d[5] + i));
                                            ^
align_simd.cc:295:7: error: ‘reg6’ was not declared in this scope
       reg6  = _mm_load_si128((VECTOR_SHORT*)(score_matrix_word + d[6] + i));
       ^~~~
align_simd.cc:295:44: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
       reg6  = _mm_load_si128((VECTOR_SHORT*)(score_matrix_word + d[6] + i));
                                            ^
align_simd.cc:296:7: error: ‘reg7’ was not declared in this scope
       reg7  = _mm_load_si128((VECTOR_SHORT*)(score_matrix_word + d[7] + i));
       ^~~~
align_simd.cc:296:44: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
       reg7  = _mm_load_si128((VECTOR_SHORT*)(score_matrix_word + d[7] + i));
                                            ^
align_simd.cc:298:7: error: ‘reg8’ was not declared in this scope
       reg8  = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(reg0,  reg1);
       ^~~~
align_simd.cc:298:45: error: ‘_mm_unpacklo_epi16’ was not declared in this scope
       reg8  = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(reg0,  reg1);
                                             ^
align_simd.cc:299:7: error: ‘reg9’ was not declared in this scope
       reg9  = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(reg0,  reg1);
       ^~~~
align_simd.cc:299:45: error: ‘_mm_unpackhi_epi16’ was not declared in this scope
       reg9  = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(reg0,  reg1);
                                             ^
align_simd.cc:300:7: error: ‘reg10’ was not declared in this scope
       reg10 = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(reg2,  reg3);
       ^~~~~
align_simd.cc:301:7: error: ‘reg11’ was not declared in this scope
       reg11 = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(reg2,  reg3);
       ^~~~~
align_simd.cc:302:7: error: ‘reg12’ was not declared in this scope
       reg12 = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(reg4,  reg5);
       ^~~~~
align_simd.cc:303:7: error: ‘reg13’ was not declared in this scope
       reg13 = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(reg4,  reg5);
       ^~~~~
align_simd.cc:304:7: error: ‘reg14’ was not declared in this scope
       reg14 = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(reg6,  reg7);
       ^~~~~
align_simd.cc:305:7: error: ‘reg15’ was not declared in this scope
       reg15 = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(reg6,  reg7);
       ^~~~~
align_simd.cc:307:7: error: ‘reg16’ was not declared in this scope
       reg16 = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(reg8,  reg10);
       ^~~~~
align_simd.cc:307:46: error: ‘_mm_unpacklo_epi32’ was not declared in this scope
       reg16 = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(reg8,  reg10);
                                              ^
align_simd.cc:308:7: error: ‘reg17’ was not declared in this scope
       reg17 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(reg8,  reg10);
       ^~~~~
align_simd.cc:308:46: error: ‘_mm_unpackhi_epi32’ was not declared in this scope
       reg17 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(reg8,  reg10);
                                              ^
align_simd.cc:309:7: error: ‘reg18’ was not declared in this scope
       reg18 = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(reg12, reg14);
       ^~~~~
align_simd.cc:310:7: error: ‘reg19’ was not declared in this scope
       reg19 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(reg12, reg14);
       ^~~~~
align_simd.cc:311:7: error: ‘reg20’ was not declared in this scope
       reg20 = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(reg9,  reg11);
       ^~~~~
align_simd.cc:312:7: error: ‘reg21’ was not declared in this scope
       reg21 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(reg9,  reg11);
       ^~~~~
align_simd.cc:313:7: error: ‘reg22’ was not declared in this scope
       reg22 = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(reg13, reg15);
       ^~~~~
align_simd.cc:314:7: error: ‘reg23’ was not declared in this scope
       reg23 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(reg13, reg15);
       ^~~~~
align_simd.cc:316:7: error: ‘reg24’ was not declared in this scope
       reg24 = _mm_unpacklo_epi64(reg16, reg18);
       ^~~~~
align_simd.cc:316:46: error: ‘_mm_unpacklo_epi64’ was not declared in this scope
       reg24 = _mm_unpacklo_epi64(reg16, reg18);
                                              ^
align_simd.cc:317:7: error: ‘reg25’ was not declared in this scope
       reg25 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(reg16, reg18);
       ^~~~~
align_simd.cc:317:46: error: ‘_mm_unpackhi_epi64’ was not declared in this scope
       reg25 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(reg16, reg18);
                                              ^
align_simd.cc:318:7: error: ‘reg26’ was not declared in this scope
       reg26 = _mm_unpacklo_epi64(reg17, reg19);
       ^~~~~
align_simd.cc:319:7: error: ‘reg27’ was not declared in this scope
       reg27 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(reg17, reg19);
       ^~~~~
align_simd.cc:320:7: error: ‘reg28’ was not declared in this scope
       reg28 = _mm_unpacklo_epi64(reg20, reg22);
       ^~~~~
align_simd.cc:321:7: error: ‘reg29’ was not declared in this scope
       reg29 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(reg20, reg22);
       ^~~~~
align_simd.cc:322:7: error: ‘reg30’ was not declared in this scope
       reg30 = _mm_unpacklo_epi64(reg21, reg23);
       ^~~~~
align_simd.cc:323:7: error: ‘reg31’ was not declared in this scope
       reg31 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(reg21, reg23);
       ^~~~~
align_simd.cc:325:37: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
       _mm_store_si128((VECTOR_SHORT*)(dprofile_word +
                                     ^
align_simd.cc:326:76: error: ‘_mm_store_si128’ was not declared in this scope
                                  CDEPTH*CHANNELS*(i+0) + CHANNELS*j), reg24);
                                                                            ^
align_simd.cc:327:37: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
       _mm_store_si128((VECTOR_SHORT*)(dprofile_word +
                                     ^
align_simd.cc:329:37: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
       _mm_store_si128((VECTOR_SHORT*)(dprofile_word +
                                     ^
align_simd.cc:331:37: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
       _mm_store_si128((VECTOR_SHORT*)(dprofile_word +
                                     ^
align_simd.cc:333:37: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
       _mm_store_si128((VECTOR_SHORT*)(dprofile_word +
                                     ^
align_simd.cc:335:37: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
       _mm_store_si128((VECTOR_SHORT*)(dprofile_word +
                                     ^
align_simd.cc:337:37: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
       _mm_store_si128((VECTOR_SHORT*)(dprofile_word +
                                     ^
align_simd.cc:339:37: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
       _mm_store_si128((VECTOR_SHORT*)(dprofile_word +
                                     ^
align_simd.cc: At global scope:
align_simd.cc:429:25: error: variable or field ‘aligncolumns_first’ declared void
 void aligncolumns_first(VECTOR_SHORT * Sm,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:429:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
align_simd.cc:429:40: error: ‘Sm’ was not declared in this scope
 void aligncolumns_first(VECTOR_SHORT * Sm,
                                        ^~
align_simd.cc:430:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT * hep,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:430:40: error: ‘hep’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT * hep,
                                        ^~~
align_simd.cc:431:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT ** qp,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:431:41: error: ‘qp’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT ** qp,
                                         ^~
align_simd.cc:432:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT QR_q_i,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:433:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT R_q_i,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:434:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT QR_q_r,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:435:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT R_q_r,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:436:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT QR_t_0,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:437:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT R_t_0,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:438:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT QR_t_1,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:439:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT R_t_1,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:440:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT QR_t_2,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:441:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT R_t_2,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:442:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT QR_t_3,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:443:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT R_t_3,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:444:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT h0,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:445:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT h1,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:446:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT h2,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:447:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT h3,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:448:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT f0,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:449:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT f1,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:450:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT f2,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:451:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT f3,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:452:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT * _h_min,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:452:40: error: ‘_h_min’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT * _h_min,
                                        ^~~~~~
align_simd.cc:453:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT * _h_max,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:453:40: error: ‘_h_max’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT * _h_max,
                                        ^~~~~~
align_simd.cc:454:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT Mm,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:455:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT M_QR_t_left,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:456:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT M_R_t_left,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:457:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT M_QR_q_interior,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:458:25: error: ‘VECTOR_SHORT’ was not declared in this scope
                         VECTOR_SHORT M_QR_q_right,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:459:33: error: expected primary-expression before ‘ql’
                         int64_t ql,
                                 ^~
align_simd.cc:460:25: error: expected primary-expression before ‘unsigned’
                         unsigned short * dir)
                         ^~~~~~~~
align_simd.cc:94:16: warning: ‘scorematrix’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static int64_t scorematrix[16][16];
                ^~~~~~~~~~~
Makefile:657 : la recette pour la cible « align_simd.o » a échouée
make[2]: *** [align_simd.o] Erreur 1
make[2] : on quitte le répertoire « /home/dylan/vsearch/src »
Makefile:377 : la recette pour la cible « all-recursive » a échouée
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Erreur 1
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /home/dylan/vsearch »
Makefile:318 : la recette pour la cible « all » a échouée
make: *** [all] Erreur 2
```

I think i miss some libraries, but not sure. Can you tell me what is wrong/missing ?

Answer (score 0):

> Can you tell me what is wrong/missing ?

It looks like all the errors flow from the very first one, about `__m128i` not being a recognized type name.  Indeed, it is not a standard C++ type, as you can tell strictly from its name: all identifiers starting with two underscores are reserved to the implementation.  The most likely explanation, then, is that the code, as it is currently being compiled, is specific to one or more particular C++ implementations, such as Intel's.  Presumably, then, on Ubuntu you were using a compiler that supported this extension (the type `__m128i`), but on Debian you are using one that does not.

That the failure occurs during the build stage and not during the configuration stage is a flaw in the project's source code or build system (but not in the Autotools themselves).  If the project indeed assumes a specific compiler then it ought to look for and set up to use that compiler, failing if it is not found.  If it can accommodate different compilers by use of, say, macro definitions provided on the command line, then `configure` ought to ensure that the correct definitions are indeed emitted.  If it is supposed to do compiler detection and adaptation in the source code, then it is not doing so successfully.

It may not be possible to build the project on your Stretch system with the tools presently available there, but you haven't provided enough information to be certain.  Things to look for:

- run `./configure --help` to look for any custom configuration options that might be applicable.
- Check project documentation for build instructions.  These might describe specific requirements that you need to satisfy.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer but i found the problem.
As it was my first debian install, i took the wrong architecture, which made me install wrong libraries. I reinstalled my debian and everything works fine now !